# How to convert a decimal number to binary in Swift?

Tags: swift

How can I convert Int to UInt8 in Swift?
Example. I want to convert number 22 to 0b00010110

```
var decimal = 22
var binary:UInt8 = ??? //What should I write here?
```

Comment: Numbers have no base until you want to display them.

Comment: `var decimal = 22;` that is it that is a binary number `1*(2^4) + 1*(2^2) + 1*2`;

Comment: your question (based on comments) is actually: "how do I XOR bytes in swift?"

Comment: @Kevin, what does that mean?

Comment: @ScottyBlades numbers are an abstract idea, numerals are simply our way of communicating them. If I have 22 apples, it doesn't matter if I say I have 22, 0b10110, 026, 0x16, or 10(base 22), I have exactly the same number of apples. Similarly, if a variable has the value 22, it doesn't matter what base you write that in, the value is still 22.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You can convert the decimal value to a human-readable binary *representation* using the `String` initializer that takes a `radix` parameter:

```
let num = 22
let str = String(num, radix: 2)
print(str) // prints "10110"
```

If you wanted to, you could also pad it with any number of zeroes pretty easily as well:

**Swift 5**

```
func pad(string : String, toSize: Int) -> String {
  var padded = string
  for _ in 0..<(toSize - string.count) {
    padded = "0" + padded
  }
  return padded
}

let num = 22
let str = String(num, radix: 2)
print(str) // 10110
pad(string: str, toSize: 8)  // 00010110
```

Comment: I need a number in UInt8. I want to work with bytes. Example to make XOR:

Comment: You can simply use the `UInt8()` initializer, and pass in an `Int` type, if you want to convert an existing `Int` to a `UInt8` type. Or if you want to assign a `UInt8` variable directly, knowing the value ahead of time, using `let myBits = 0b00010110`.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me. How can I println(UInt8)? I want to see bytes instead of decimal value.

Comment: My answer should help you with that.

Comment: radix is no longer available

Comment: @ScottyBlades Are you sure? It looks like it's still in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2885001-init

Comment: You're right, I must have written it wrong.  I copied and pasted, now its working.

Comment: repeatElement ("0", count : 8 - str.count ) + str )

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 5 / Xcode 14**

Thanks **Gustavo Seidler**.
My version of his solution is **complemented by spaces** for **readability**.

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    var binaryDescription: String {
        var binaryString = ""
        var internalNumber = self
        var counter = 0
        
        for _ in (1...self.bitWidth) {
            binaryString.insert(contentsOf: "\(internalNumber & 1)", at: binaryString.startIndex)
            internalNumber >>= 1
            counter += 1
            if counter % 4 == 0 {
                binaryString.insert(contentsOf: " ", at: binaryString.startIndex)
            }
        }

        return binaryString
    }
}
```

**Examples:**

```
UInt8(9).binaryDescription      // "0000 1001"
Int8(5).binaryDescription       // "0000 0101"
UInt16(1945).binaryDescription  // "0000 0111 1001 1001"

Int16(14).binaryDescription     // "0000 0000 0000 1110"
Int32(6).binaryDescription      // "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0110"
UInt32(2018).binaryDescription  // "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1110 0010"
```

Answer (score 9):

Went through a lot of answers on this post but I wonder why haven't anyone mentioned the API `leadingZeroBitCount` on FixedWidthInteger

This returns the number of zeros in specific UInt
eg:

```
UInt(4).leadingZeroBitCount //61

UInt16(4).leadingZeroBitCount //13
```

**Swift Version**

```
4.1
```

**USAGE**

```
let strFive = String.binaryRepresentation(of: UInt8(5))
print(strFive) // Prints: 00000101
```

**UNDER THE HOOD**

```
extension String {

    static func binaryRepresentation<F: FixedWidthInteger>(of val: F) -> String {

        let binaryString = String(val, radix: 2)

        if val.leadingZeroBitCount > 0 {
            return String(repeating: "0", count: val.leadingZeroBitCount) + binaryString
        }

        return binaryString
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I modified someone's version to swift 3.0 used the correct initializer for creating a string with repeated values

```
extension String {
    func pad(with character: String, toLength length: Int) -> String {
        let padCount = length - self.characters.count
        guard padCount > 0 else { return self }

        return String(repeating: character, count: padCount) + self
    }
}

String(37, radix: 2).pad(with: "0", toLength: 8) // "00100101"
```

Answer (score 8):

Since none of the solutions contemplate negative numbers, I came up with a simple solution that basically reads the number's internal representation and pads it automatically to the width of its type. This should work on all `BinaryInteger` types.

```swift
extension BinaryInteger {
    var binaryDescription: String {
        var binaryString = ""
        var internalNumber = self
        for _ in (1...self.bitWidth) {
            binaryString.insert(contentsOf: "\(internalNumber & 1)", at: binaryString.startIndex)
            internalNumber >>= 1
        }
        return "0b" + binaryString
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
UInt8(22).binaryDescription     // "0b00010110"
Int8(60).binaryDescription      // "0b00111100"
Int8(-60).binaryDescription     // "0b11000100"
Int16(255).binaryDescription    // "0b0000000011111111"
Int16(-255).binaryDescription   // "0b1111111100000001"
```

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the others, Although the for-loop seems redundant for repeating a character.
we can simply go with the following String initialiser:

```
init(count count: Int, repeatedValue c: Character)
```

usage example:

```
let string = String(count: 5, repeatedValue: char)
```

Here is a full example:

```
let someBits: UInt8 = 0b00001110
let str = String(someBits, radix:2) //binary base
let padd = String(count: (8 - str.characters.count), repeatedValue: Character("0")) //repeat a character
print(padd + str)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want `binary` to have the value of `22`, just assign it that: `binary = 22` or you could write it as `binary = 0b00010110`; the two statements are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it:

```
extension String {
    public func pad(with padding: Character, toLength length: Int) -> String {
        let paddingWidth = length - self.characters.count
        guard 0 < paddingWidth else { return self }

        return String(repeating: padding, count: paddingWidth) + self
    }
}

String(0b1010, radix: 2).pad(with: "0", toLength: 8) //00001010
```

Comment: What's unavailable?

Answer (score 3):

So I had this come up recently. The other generic solutions didn't work for me, due to various issues. Anyway, here's my solution (Swift 4):

```
extension String {
  init<B: FixedWidthInteger>(fullBinary value: B) {
    self = value.words.reduce(into: "") {
      $0.append(contentsOf: repeatElement("0", count: $1.leadingZeroBitCount))
      $0.append(String($1, radix: 2))
    }
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
// result: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001
String(fullBinary: 9)
// result: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000
String(fullBinary: -256)

// result: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101100011110001
String(fullBinary: -9999)
// result: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010011100001111
String(fullBinary: 9999)

// result: 1100011000000000000000000000000000000000000011110110100110110101
String(fullBinary: 14267403619510741429 as UInt)
```

Comment: just saw this. I posted a similar approach. this looks clever and cleaner

Answer (score 3):

swift 4.1

```
extension String {
    public func pad(with padding: Character, toLength length: Int) -> String {
        let paddingWidth = length - self.count
        guard 0 < paddingWidth else { return self }

        return String(repeating: padding, count: paddingWidth) + self
    }
}


extension UInt8 {
     public func toBits() -> String
     {
          let a = String( self, radix : 2 )
          let b = a.pad(with: "0", toLength: 8)
          return b
     }
}

func showBits( _ list: [UInt8] )
{
    for num in list
    {
        showBits(num)
    }
}

func showBits( _ num: UInt8 )
{
    //print(num, String( num, radix : 2 ))
    print( "\(num) \t" +   num.toBits())
}

let initialBits :UInt8 = 0b00001111
let invertedBits = ~initialBits
showBits( [initialBits, invertedBits] )
```

**result**

15  00001111

240 11110000

good for you~

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between binary and decimal numeral systems, when you're working with variables until you want to visualize them or if you want to convert types which can hold different ammount of bits.

In your case is enough to write

```
var decimal = 22
var binary = UInt8(decimal)
```

But this will crash (overflow happens) if `decimal` will hold a value more than 255, because it is maximum value which `UInt8` can hold.

Depending on what you want to achieve you can write

```
var decimal = 261 // 0b100000101
var binary = UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: decimal) // 0b00000101
```

You'll get `0` as a result, because this initializer will truncate less significant bits.

Second option is

```
var decimal = 256  // 0b100000000
var binary = UInt8(exactly: decimal) // nil
```

This initializer returns `nil` result instead of crashing, if overflow happens.

P.S. If you want to see binary string representation use

```
String(decimal, radix: 2)
String(binary, radix: 2)
```

Comment: UInt8(decimal), and UInt8(exactly: do not produce binary representations.  TruncatingBitPattern isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your version to Swift 2.0 count on strings and added a length check:

```
extension String {
 func pad(length: Int) -> String {
    let diff = length - self.characters.count
    if diff > 0 {
        var padded = self
        for _ in 0..<diff {
            padded = "0" + padded
        }
        return padded
    } else {
        return self
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most answers here forget to account for 0, and outputs a representation there is too long.

Based on the answer by @karwag I present:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var binaryStringRepresentation: String {
        words.reduce(into: "") {
            $0.append(contentsOf: repeatElement("0", count: $1.leadingZeroBitCount))
            if $1 != 0 {
                $0.append(String($1, radix: 2))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit overcomplicated, but very fast.
It separates every 4 bits, leaving no white spaces in the string.

```
extension BinaryInteger {

    var binaryDescription: String {
        var string = ""
        var num = self
        let range: UInt64
        switch self.bitWidth {
            case 8:  range = 0x80
            case 16: range = 0x8000
            case 32: range = 0x80000000
            case 64: range = 0x8000000000000000
            default: range = 0x0
        }   
        
        if Self.isSigned {          
            let mask = Self(range / 2)
            let last = num & 1
            num >>= 1
            
            for i in 1...self.bitWidth-1 {
                string.append("\(num & mask == mask ? 1 : 0)")
                num <<= 1
                if i % 4 == 0 { string.append(" ") }
            }
            
            string.append("\(last)")
                        
        } else { // Unsigned
    
            let mask = Self(range)

            for i in 1...self.bitWidth {
                string.append("\(num & mask == mask ? 1 : 0)")
                num <<= 1
                if i % 4 == 0 { string.append(" ") }
            }
            
            string = String(string.dropLast())          
        }
        
        return string
    }   
}
```

Examples:

```
UInt8(245).binaryDescription  // 1111 0101
Int8(108).binaryDescription   // 0110 1100
```