# Swift - Turn Int to binary representations

Tags: swift, bitmask

I receive an Int from my server which I’d like to explode in to an array of bit masks. So for example, if my server gives me the number 3, we get two values, a binary 1 and a binary 2.

How do I do this in Swift?

Comment: Probably in this [](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267089/convert-a-two-byte-uint8-array-to-a-uint16-in-swift) you can find interest: let data= NSData(array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a decimal number to binary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181221/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-to-binary-in-swift)

Answer (score 6):

You could use:

```
let number = 3
//radix: 2 is binary, if you wanted hex you could do radix: 16
let str = String(number, radix: 2)
println(str)
```

prints "11"

```
let number = 79
//radix: 2 is binary, if you wanted hex you could do radix: 16
let str = String(number, radix: 16)
println(str)
```

prints "4f"

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any nice built-in way, but you could use this:

```
var i = 3
let a = 0..<8

var b = a.map { Int(i & (1 << $0)) }
// b = [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward implementation:

```
func intToMasks(var n: Int) -> [Int] {
    var masks = [Int]()
    var mask = 1
    while n > 0 {
        if n & mask > 0 {
            masks.append(mask)
            n -= mask
        }
        mask <<= 1
    }
    return masks
}

println(intToMasks(3))    // prints "[1,2]"
println(intToMasks(1000)) // prints "[8,32,64,128,256,512]"
```

Answer (score 1):

```swift
public extension UnsignedInteger {
  /// The digits that make up this number.
  /// - Parameter radix: The base the result will use.
  func digits(radix: Self = 10) -> [Self] {
    sequence(state: self) { quotient in
      guard quotient > 0
      else { return nil }

      let division = quotient.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: radix)
      quotient = division.quotient
      return division.remainder
    }
    .reversed()
  }
}
```

```swift
let digits = (6 as UInt).digits(radix: 0b10) // [1, 1, 0]
digits.reversed().enumerated().map { $1 << $0 } // [0, 2, 4]
```

Reverse the result too, if you need it.