# How I can convert int to binary string swift?

Tags: swift, binary

I have such int number:

```
266
```

I would like to convert it to binary string. In android I use such method:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(266)
```

and the output was:

```
000100001010
```

I ios I tried to use string with radix:

```
String(266, radix: 2)
```

but I got:

```
100001010
```

I found such [question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181323/9363441) and used such code:

```
func pad(string : String, toSize: Int) -> String {
      var padded = string
      for _ in 0..<(toSize - string.count) {
        padded = "0" + padded
      }
        return padded
    }
```

and:

```
pad(string: String(ResumeController.userData.edu!), toSize: 12)
```

and got:

```
000100001010
```

can you please explain why external function which added some 0s works similar to the kotlin one which is built-in? And also one more question - how I can get this number back from this binary string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function that can convert to integer `Int("000100001010", radix: 2)`
To append zeroes, use this:
`let str = String(repeating: "0", count: amount)`