# Swift: How can I print the bitfields of a struct?

Tags: swift, bit-fields

For a struct defined as below, I am looking for a method that would print all the members of the struct, including the bitfields.

```
public struct A {

    public var privateVar0 : UInt32
    public var bit_1 : UInt32 {
        get {
            return privateVar0 >> 0 & 0b00000000000000000000000000000001
        }
    }

    public var bit_2 : UInt32 {
        get {
            return privateVar0 >> 1 & 0b00000000000000000000000000000001
        }
    }

    public var bit_3 : UInt32 {
        get {
            return privateVar0 >> 2 & 0b00000000000000000000000000000001
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
privateVar0 : <Value>
bit_1 : <Value>
bit_2 : <Value>
bit_3 : <Value>
```

I have tried to use the dump() in-built API that uses Mirror, but it prints only "privateVar0" and not the bitfields.

Comment: `bit_X` are computed properties. They are not stored as part of the struct.

Comment: Maybe some look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181221/how-to-convert-a-decimal-number-to-binary-in-swift ? You can also make your structure conforms to CustomStringConvertible

Comment: As Sweeper said, these properties are not in the actual `A` struct. Also, you can clean this up a bit by replacing the `0b00000000000000000000000000000001` with just `1` since it conveys the same meaning and shorter. Less prone to mistakes if you accidentally delete a `0`, for example.